# how can I make a trigger at max points (first and last one) of my enveloped signal?

Tags: verilog

I wrote this code, but the first trigger is correct, but I don't know why comes the second & third trigger at the second and also pre-last peak and the trigger for the last one (also as the second max) does not make!

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module peak (
    input clk,
    input signed [15:0] envelope,
    output reg trigger
    );

reg signed [15:0] prev_envelope;
reg signed [15:0] derivative;
reg peak_detected = 0;
parameter signed [15:0] threshold = 3000;

always @(clk) begin
    derivative <= envelope - prev_envelope;

    if (derivative < 0 && envelope > threshold && !peak_detected) begin
        trigger <= 1;
        peak_detected <= 1;
    end else begin
        trigger <= 0;
        if (envelope < threshold) begin
            peak_detected <= 0; // Reset peak_detected when envelope drops below threshold
        end
    end

    prev_envelope <= envelope;
end

endmodule
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The statement

`derivative <= envelope - prev_envelope;`

subtracts a 16 bit number from a 16 bit number then stores the result in a 16 bit number.
The result (derivative) needs to be 17 bits to support the full domain of the variables being subtracted.

Here is a reference for bit growth: [bit growth in FPGA arithmetic](https://zipcpu.com/dsp/2017/07/21/bit-growth.html)

Its not possible to determine if there are other issues without a testbench.